# Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ such that $A^{2} = A$. Prove that every $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be decomposed as $v = v_{1} + v_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ such that $A^{2} = A$. Prove that every $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be decomposed as $v = v_{1} + v_{2}$, where $v_{1}$ is in the nullspace of $A$ and $v_{2}$ is in the column space of $A$.

My reasoning:

1. I would first consider the matrix equation $Ax = b$.
2. The vector $b$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
3. $b$ is either in the column  space of $A$ or not in the column space of $A$.
4. $b$ is either in the column space of $A$ or in the nullspace of $A$.
5. Thus, $b$ = $v$ can be expressed as the linear combination of $v_{1} + v_{2}$.

My reasoning is extremely fuzzy and this is the best I could think of. I personally am not convinced by Step 2 onwards. I would appreciate it if someone could strengthen my reasoning, or point out why it is wrong, and offer a better proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit for your effort. Here's a better proof, with a trick involved that you would do well to remember.

Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$.Then, we write $x = (Ax) + (x - Ax)$. We know that $Ax \in \operatorname{im} A$ (where $\operatorname{im}$ denotes column space or image). The key point here is:
$$
A(x - Ax) = Ax - A(Ax) = Ax - A^2x = 0
$$

Which means that $x-Ax \in \ker A$, where $\ker$ denotes the kernel or null space.

However, we have written $x$  as a sum of an element in the column space ($Ax$) and the null space ($x - Ax$).

This completes the proof. The trick, of course, was in realizing that $x-Ax$ is actually in the kernel of $A$.

In fact the decomposition is *unique*. To do this, show that the intersection of the column and null space is actually trivial (only contains zero). This is a very strong statement, which even has repercussions in infinite dimensions (there are similar statements).

Comment: By this, I hope you will remember this trick!

Comment: This is a good trick. Thanks! Regarding your statement that the decomposition is unique, could you elaborate further? I could see that the intersection of the spaces is trivial, but I couldn't see how it would lead to the conclusion that the decomposition would be unique.

Comment: Once you have seen that the intersection is trivial, then suppose that $x = v_1+w_1 = v_2 + w_2$, where $v_1, v_2$ are in the column space and $w_1,w_2$ are in the null space. Then, we get $v_1-v_2 = w_1-w_2$. Therefore, $v_1-v_2$ is in the column space, but because it's equal to $w_1-w_2$, it's also in the null space, because $w_1-w_2$ is. However, we know the intersection is trivial, hence $v_1-v_2 = 0 \implies v_1 = v_2$, so $w_1=w_2$, hence the representation of $x$ is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$v=\underbrace{(I-A)v}_{v_1}+\underbrace{Av}_{v_2}$$

- $v_1 \in Ker A$ because its image by $A$ is $A(I-A)(v_1)=(A-A^2)(v_1)=0.$
- $v_2$ is in the column space of $A$ because of its very form.